# what's the default timeout of func

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova

all,I'm using redhat func,I can't find the default timeout of func.
in the source code like below:

```
self.timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
# the config file
if self.overlord_config.socket_timeout != 0.0:
    self.timeout = self.overlord_config.socket_timeout
# commandline
if timeout:
    self.timeout = timeout
```

DEFAULT_TIMEOUT is none in the source code

```
 DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = None
```

in the overloard_config,defalut is:

```
# configuration for overlord

[main]
socket_timeout = 0
```

and timeout is not assigned,so the default is none from the contructor:

```
class Overlord(object):

    def __init__(self, server_spec, port=DEFAULT_PORT, interactive=False,
        verbose=False, noglobs=False, nforks=1, config=None, async=False, init_ssl=True,
        delegate=False, mapfile=DEFAULT_MAPLOC, timeout=None):
```

so my question is what's the defalut timeout of func? is it depended by http client?

Comment: timeouts can be implemented using the signal package. If you are looking at implementing your own timeout method in your class look into this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-python-function-call

Comment: I just wanto know what's the default timeout of func